# Disable profile editing for one single account

Tags: php, wordpress, profile, user-profile

I have made a public account in wordpress which I will send to 100 users.
 
So the login would be:

Username: public
Password: 123example

The only thing I want is to hide the profile page for this specific user account so they can't change password, emailadress, etc.

How to achieve this? Maybe change some php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script cover all the aspects of the question, read the code comments for further explanation.

```
<?php
/**
 * this make sure the public user where redirected
 * to home instead of profile page
 */
function redirect_user_to($redirect_to, $request, $user)
{
  global $user;
  if ($user->user_login == 'public') {
    return home_url();
  }
  else {
    return home_url("/wp-admin/");
  }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_user_to', 10, 3);

/**
 * this remove the profile links from
 * the top nav menu
 */
function remove_edit_profile()
{
  global $wp_admin_bar, $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ($current_user->user_login == 'public') {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account-with-avatar');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');
  }
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_edit_profile', 0);

/**
 * this remove the "Site Admin" link from
 * the WP meta widget, usually placed in
 * the side bar.
 */
function my_unregister_widgets()
{
  unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
  register_widget('MY_Widget_Meta');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_unregister_widgets');

class MY_Widget_Meta extends WP_Widget
{

  function MY_Widget_Meta()
  {
    $widget_ops = array(
      'classname' => 'widget_meta',
      'description' => __("Log in/out, admin, feed and WordPress links"),
    );
    $this->WP_Widget('meta', __('Meta'), $widget_ops);
  }

  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args);
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? __('Meta') : $instance['title']);
    echo $before_widget;
    if ($title) {
      echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
    }
    ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php
        global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if ($current_user->user_login == 'public') {
    }
    else {
      wp_register();
    }
    ?>
<li>
<?php wp_loginout();?>
</li>
<li>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url');?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(__('Syndicate this site using RSS 2.0'));?>">
    <?php _e('Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr>');?></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url');?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(__('The latest comments to all posts in RSS'));?>">
    <?php _e('Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr>');?></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="<?php echo esc_attr(__('Powered by WordPress, state-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform.'));?>">WordPress.org</a>
</li>
<?php wp_meta();?>
</ul>
        <?php
                echo $after_widget;
  }
}

/**
 * this prevent from non authorized user ( public )
 * to pointing to the profile page by writing into
 * the address bar.
 */
function force_profile_redirect()
{
  global $pagenow, $current_user;
  if (strtolower($current_user->user_login) == 'public') {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
  }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_profile_redirect');
?>
```

Comment: The last redirect portion here could be a little bit more WP friendly, albeit a very slight performance decrease. Arg, see my answer below for code.

Answer (score 2):

The last portion in @aSeptik's answer could be a little more WP friendly.

```
function force_profile_redirect() {
    global $pagenow, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if ($pagenow == 'profile.php' && $current_user->user_login == 'public') {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }   
}
add_action('admin_init', 'force_profile_redirect');
```

Comment: there are two things you don't need in your script. one is the  get_currentuserinfo(); and then the $pagenow == 'profile.php'

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to modify your profile page code, to make it not show the editable areas, and not run the "update profile" action, if the user ID is [xyz].

For the page which actually does the updating of the profile, you can just put at the top something like

```
// Change this line to match however you identify your logged-in user
// And change the id number to the ID of the public user
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ($current_user->ID == 1)
{
    // Stop them seeing this page
    header('Location: index.php');
    // And for good measure
    die();
}
```

For the page on which they can change the profile fields before they submit the form, you can do something like this

```
// Change this line to match however you identify your logged-in user
// And change the id number to the ID of the public user
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ($current_user->ID == 1)
{
    // Say no
    echo '<p>You cannot edit your profile on this account.</p>';
    // And for good measure
    die();
}
```

Without seeing your code, it's hard to be more specific, but this should work at a push, even if it's not exactly how you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I am not realy a coder, but I know how to edit code. Could you please describe in code how to change this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow, I gtg now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sry I can't get it working :-( I do need to update the profile.php file with the above info right? and replace the number 1 to the ID number of the ID number of the public account right?

Comment: Updated the answer to have the Wordpress code in there - copy the code and replace 1 with the ID of the public account.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I have placed the first code in the profile.php and I get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id() in /myurl/wp-admin/profile.php on line 11

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I got the function used in WordpressMU :) Give it a shot with the re-updated code, and see how that one goes.

Comment: thanks for your effort Joe, but still got this error: atal error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in mydomain/wp-admin/profile.php It's the profile.php that needs to be updated right?